# Slide-able Time Range Picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How to implement Time Range selector in flutter as shown below.
I have tried almost every package in pub.dev yet unable to find any library that offers such functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [video_trimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer)
[image]

or this: [video_editor](https://pub.dev/packages/video_editor)
[image]